# Is there an Application Management Console for Jetty?

Tags: jetty

I've fairly recently started working with Java (most of my recent experience is in .NET).  As part of that effort, I have been doing some comparison between Jetty and Tomcat.

One feature of Tomcat that I think would be useful in our environment is the built in management console that allows an administrator to deploy/undeploy/restart/etc the various applications deployed to the server.

Is there a similar capability available for Jetty?  If not, is there a preferred way to manage application servers?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

Any JMX console should work, including JConsole and JVisualVM.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but I am looking for a management web app like the one built into Tomcat.  I don't think that a JMX console is quite what I am looking for.

Comment: The consoles you mention are great tools for general inspection of the JVM. They cannot be used to manage features specific for the applications server (like install/remove the application).

Comment: Well, they *can* if those features are exposed. I don't know if they are in the case of Jetty.

Comment: You can enable JMX in Jetty to allow for this: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jmx-chapter.html